# После публикации Веб приложения Visual Studio 2019 ASP.CORE.NET 2.1 не работает авторизация и нет доступа к базе MySQL ASP.CORE.NET 2.1

Tags: веб-программирование, framework, iis, entity

Есть приложение не мое. Нужно опубликовать и положить на сервер.
На рабочей станции после компиляции все работает. Подключается к базе, отображает HTML и т.д.
На сервере же выдает 404 http://93.183.214.167:2324/api/Auth
Auth - контроллер авторизации.
Можно собственно посмотреть по адресу http://93.183.214.167:2324/login.html
Что делал.
Настраивал IIS, пул приложений и т.д.
Запускал dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
Устанавливал dotnet hosting, sdk, runtime....
После всех манипуляций обнаружился затык в entity framework migrations 
Если миграцию отключить то публикует, но не работает на сервере.
Если включить миграцию выводит

```
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'ScadaContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ScadaContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(215,5): Ошибка : Entity framework SQL Script generation failed
```

Вот код контекста

```
  public class ScadaContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public ScadaContext(DbContextOptions<ScadaContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                   .Build();
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ScadaContext");
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант имплементировать `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>`

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<CodingBlastDbContext>
{
    public CodingBlastDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CodingBlastDbContext>();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new CodingBlastDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

пример выше из этого [источника](https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/).